# How to find within aggregation with mapped id for the collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find the count of `"studentId"` where `"classId"` is `"cls12sc"` and `"subjectId"` is `"19690112"` and this `"subjectId"` is different everytimes using aggregation. Here `"classId"` is passed dynamically and from this `"classId"` i have to get `"subjectId"` count associated with the `"classId"` which matched to `"subjectId"` and `"sScore"` condition.
Here is my collection(Students) Json data:

Schema:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53f63fc8f2b643f6ebb8a1a9"),
"subjectId" : 19690112,
"studentId" : "ads5ad2",
"sScore" : 25
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53f63fc8f2b643f6ebb8a1a2"),
"subjectId" : 19690112,
"studentId" : "s5sdf45",
"sScore" : 85
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53f63fc8f2b643f6ebb8a902"),
"subjectId" : 19690112,
"classId" : "cls12sc",
"sScore" : 64
}
```

See this attached image for better clarity[image]

Here is my aggregation pipeline:

```
var classId = "cls12sc" ;
var subjectId = "19690112";
db.Students.aggregate([
  {$match:{"classId" : classId, "subjectId": subjectId }},
  {$group:{"_id" : "$subjectId", count: { $sum: 1 }}}
]);
```

But i don't want to use var declaration two time from same collection. I want to pass just `classId`. From `classId` it should fetch `subjectId` and get count.
See the possible collection data with output possibility:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f63fc8f2b643f6ebb8a1a9"),
    "subjectId" : 19690112,
    "studentId" : "ads5ad2",
    "sScore" : 25
    },
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f63fc8f2b643f6ebb8a1a2"),
    "subjectId" : 19690112,
    "studentId" : "s5sdf45",
    "sScore" : 85
    },
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f63fc8f2b643f6ebb8a902"),
    "subjectId" : 19690112,
    "classId" : "cls12sc",
    "sScore" : 64
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53Ro6GpGjJTeam2JxfN"), 
    "subjectId" : "567818ec20a3d410709bb202", 
    "studentId" : "kobo2WfCpN7RHMxi7",
    "sScore" : 89
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53badBbn9dnv88qXdrT"), 
    "subjectId" : "567818ec20a3d410709bb202", 
    "studentId" : "AYQ48otoD345ZWAumnMD",
    "sScore" : 8
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53pLhmMajApQDDzhonf"), 
    "subjectId" : "567818ec20a3d410709bb202", 
    "studentId" : "czASSwXvaeRA2ZXfp", 
    "sScore" : "12"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53g4tCFQFhobasRCkTy"), 
    "subjectId" : "567818ec20a3d410709bb202", 
    "classId" : "AYQ48otoDZWAumnMD",
    "sScore" : 77
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53TkCfKE29ZCsXJv7CZ"), 
    "subjectId" : "567814d620a3d410709b91ba", 
    "studentId" : "5yJdSrdrLKt9DDQRW",
    "sScore" : 20
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("538JruGLRnMDaE4gyc3"), 
    "subjectId" : "567814d620a3d410709b91ba", 
    "classId" : "5yJdSrdrLKt9DDQRW",
    "sScore" : 66
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("533Qu3zt5suR8ymkRJ6"), 
    "subjectId" : "567814d620a3d410709b91ba", 
    "studentId" : "AYQ48ot234h4oDZWAumnMD",
    "sScore" : 99
}

input 
if classId == "5yJdSrdrLKt9DDQRW" and "sScore" == 99
then 
output : 3

input 
if classId == "AYQ48otoDZWAumnMD" and "sScore" == 99
then 
output : 4
```

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: @chridam i have updated my aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @chridam see the details with more documents and output result based on input.

Comment: @chridam thanks it works for me, but what if i want extra condition like "sScore" == 99?

Comment: @chidam can you please update your answer with above suggestion, i'm not able update it, it showing me zero result?

Comment: Can you please update your question with this extra request, otherwise [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions/130630) are not encouraged here on SO? It seems to me the extra filter if introduced early in the pipeline will of course return fewer documents to the next pipeline and thus the results will be different.

Comment: @chidam i have updated question with input condition.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following pipeline to get the desired result:

```
var classId = "AYQ48otoDZWAumnMD";
db.Students.aggregate([    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$subjectId",
            "classId": { 
                "$max": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gt": ["$classId", null] },
                        "$classId", null
                    ]
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "classId": classId } }        
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : "567818ec20a3d410709bb202",
    "classId" : "AYQ48otoDZWAumnMD",
    "count" : 4
}
```

---

In the above **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline, you need to group all the documents by the `subjectId` key, but further down the pipeline you need a `classId` key that you want to filter the grouped documents by. Since some of the documents do not have the `classId` field, you would need a mechanism to create this field within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline using the [available accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/); so a good hack would be to use the **[`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)** operator to return either an existing classId field or a placeholder null value, all through the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** tenary operator which evaluates the existence of a field by using the [BSON Types Comparison Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order).

The last **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline will filter the documents to return those matching the given `classId` value on the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline created field.